# IO Server that acts as a broker

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Hi I need to build a IO server that is like a broker.

A Webserver talks to the server(broker) to make requests, like what devices are available to control. eg. embedded systems.. that is connected to the server via rs232 or usb and ethernet.

The webserver for example talks to Device A and ask to do X.

The server(broker) also talks to the devices. when device starts up, it register itself to the broker. I am device b and my name is k, im ready to take commands.

I'm using debian linux, I need to get an idea how can i pull this of.

Does this requires creating a kernel device?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:** I just read about Daemon Programming here http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html. I copied and pasted the code here.

I wrote down comments on what part of the code I will change.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) { // change this to "int main(int argc,char *argv[])"

        /* Our process ID and Session ID */
        pid_t pid, sid;

        /* Fork off the parent process */
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* If we got a good PID, then
           we can exit the parent process. */
        if (pid > 0) {
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        /* Change the file mode mask */
        umask(0);

        /* Open any logs here */        

        /* Create a new SID for the child process */
        sid = setsid();
        if (sid < 0) {
                /* Log the failure */
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }



        /* Change the current working directory */
        if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
                /* Log the failure */
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Close out the standard file descriptors */
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);

        /* Daemon-specific initialization goes here */

        /* The Big Loop */
        while (1) {
           /* Do some task here ... */  // Device detect here. eg(/dev/ttyS0-usb-serial)

           sleep(30); /* wait 30 seconds */  // Instead of using 30 seconds here I plan on removing it and changing it with events like wake up when new device is plugged.
        }
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

this code

```
int main(void)
```

change to this

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
```

so i can send commands from the command line of debian.

I'll add this code inside while loop - the big loop

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "status")==0){

    //check status of devices here  

    } 

if(new Device plugged){ // not real code. just to get the idea.
// register the device type and name.
}
```

Then using shell_exec() in php.

```
<?php $output = shell_exec('daemon status'); echo "$output"; die;
```

Sample Output in php would be something like this:

```
Device Name |  Status

/dev/ttyS0  =  online
/dev/sample =  offline
```

Is what I'm thinking workable?.

Answer (score 0):

RS232, usb and ethernet connected devices do not require new drivers in general.

You just need to create a daemon program that talks to the devices and a cgi executed on the web server that through IPC talks to the daemon and exchanges commands and results. You could try and have a simpler devices, i.e. reading the devices from the cgi, but in this case you risk to have high latency and not to be altro to react to the devices inputs.

Having said that, the formulation of the problem is too generic to give more suggestions. What do the devices do? Which languages do you want to use?

Comment: A good choice for your IPC mechanism is [dbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus).  You have your daemon process expose a end-point on the system bus, and your webservice call if when requests are received.  There are dbus bindings for just about every conceivable implementation technology you could use for the webservice.  I'd imagine PHP or Python would be the obvious ones.

Comment: @Ottavio - thanks for the answer, I plan to use c as the language. Yes that's what im also thinking creating an application/program in debian that talks to devices like what you said daemon program. so the webservice will send commands to this program reads it and check what devices are available to use. the devices controls motors(e.g. stepper, dc, servo). Is there any tutorial out there on how to create a daemon program for detecting devices if it's online or not?.

Comment: @Marko - thanks Marko, Yes PHP is my target webservice.. php sends commands to debian which then the program(daemon) reads and executes based on the command sent by the webservice. I plan on sending strings of text to send to the program e.g(status - for available devices) or stream of bytes like "01" command for status. Is what am thinking applicable for this?. thanks a lot

Comment: I have a not too different project. I use message queue, as explained in Unix Network Programming vol 2. My cgi is written in C, but by googling I see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.msg-send.php that is also works in php. By organizing smartly your code, you can also have different inputs talking at the device concurrently.